# Trying to use a COM component

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, com

I have a COM component. I registered it using regsvr32 on my 32-bit XP machine. Now when i try to instantiate a class from it in my CONSOLE application, the application just terminates, without giving any exception. Any suggestion??

The COM dll is ABCServer.dll. The code that fails,

```
   try
   {
     ILookUp LP = new LookUp();
     ABCServer Svr = LP.LookUpServer(hostname, port);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(ex.message);
   }
```

Control never reaches line 2, while debugging when i click F10 when being on line 1, the application just terminates

Comment: Did you try using `try..except`? Show us some code please...

Comment: It's worth posting the code for more clarity

Comment: Did you check your eventlog for any errors?

Comment: Does it also "just terminate" when you run it under debugger or does it actually produce an unhandled exception?

Comment: Yes the code is already inside try...catch, no entries i found in windows event log.

Comment: Why don't you check what happens in the catch? (i.e. catch something and check the error)

Comment: No exception occurs, control never reaches catch or the 2nd line, console window is closed and application abruptly terminates. I have tried unregistering and re-registering the COM dll

Comment: Your catch does not catch anything, so how do you know if anything would be caught? e.g. `catch (System.Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }`

Comment: K my mistake. Edited code in my question. The catch clause is just never reached.

Comment: @Marco he is working in C# try-execpt is only C/C++ right?

Comment: Does this code even work if you port it to standard Win32 C++ with no .NET?  E.g. suppose you call CoCreateInstance on LookUp class and then QueryInterface to get ILookUp. Does that work? Do you get a successful or failing HRESULT?  Or does your C++ project also crash?  Maybe the COM component has a buggy QueryInterface or other related supporting infrastructure.  There's a lot of details like that with COM which are easy to screw up, and going from C# to unmanaged C++ might help uncover what some of those are.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/26/96777.aspx for a taste.

Comment: Another thought would be to try running the application (either the original C# or the proposed unmanaged C++ program) with Microsoft Application Verifier.  This might uncover some issues with the underlying COM component that are causing your problem.  I've used Application Verifier before and found it to be very useful for finding subtle memory errors, that sort of thing.  (E.g. maybe the COM component is causing nasty heap corruption problems?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The COM code probably calls the C/C++ `abort()` for some reason (or whatever the equivalent is in the COM DLL's implementation language). And since the COM server is in-process, that immediately kills the whole process.

Note that C++ exceptions cannot pass through the COM boundary (they must be explicitly "marshaled" via `ISupportErrorInfo`). If an exception was raised in the COM DLL but was not properly caught and handled by the COM DLL implementation code, this might have caused `abort()` to be called.

If you have debug information for COM DLL, you can try enabling unmanaged code debugging (from Debug tab of project properties, or through "Select" button in the Attach to Process dialog) and stepping into the native COM code to try and diagnose the root problem.